# The touched window has not finished processing certain input events(Very often i am getting crash.I have no idea totally)

Tags: android

This is my crash log :

2018-11-01 15:24:09.368 3706-3722/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.bs.commerce (com.bs.commerce/.MainActivity)  PID: 21171
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 8.  Wait queue head age: 20667.0ms.)

```
Load: 4.34 / 4.6 / 3.52
CPU usage from 14871ms to 0ms ago (2018-11-01 15:23:51.186 to 2018-11-01 15:24:06.057):
  100% 21171/com.bs.commerce: 100% user + 0% kernel / faults: 270 minor
  22% 3706/system_server: 12% user + 9.8% kernel / faults: 32277 minor 1378 major
  11% 18962/com.dewmobile.kuaiya.play: 8.5% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 468 minor 8 major
  9% 4783/com.google.android.gms: 6.7% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 10036 minor 454 major
  5.9% 4038/com.android.systemui: 4.4% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 9658 minor 306 major
  4.3% 3154/surfaceflinger: 1.5% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 205 minor
  0.6% 14475/adbd: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 6455 minor 8 major
  3.3% 4277/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 2.2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 3883 minor 1440 major
  2.8% 943/kswapd0: 0% user + 2.8% kernel
  2.3% 2991/logd: 0.4% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 1870 minor 1099 major
  0.7% 22499/com.samsung.android.MtpApplication: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 5933 minor 10 major
  1.1% 2975/kworker/4:2: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
  0% 1345/kworker/6:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0.2% 4747/com.sec.android.app.launcher: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3758 minor 379 major
  0.8% 21987/com.facebook.katana: 0.7% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3014 minor 5 major
  0.6% 4954/android.process.media: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1595 minor 380 major
  0.6% 17509/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
  0.6% 22816/com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor: 0.6% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1510 minor 7 major
  0.1% 1965/kworker/5:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.5% 3217/kworker/u17:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
  0.4% 3153/servicemanager: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 4 minor
  0.4% 4062/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 54 minor
  0.4% 1833/decon0: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
  0.4% 4218/com.android.phone: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 464 minor 60 major
  0.1% 22339/com.samsung.cmh:CMH: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 325 minor
  0.1% 3152/lmkd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.2% 1213/hwrng: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0.1% 2983/jbd2/sda17-8: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 4644/com.android.nfc: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1020 minor 91 major
  0.2% 10518/com.android.vending: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1627 minor 801 major
  0% 13877/com.samsung.android.sm.devicesecurity: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 370 minor 35 major
  0.1% 21370/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1480 minor
  0.2% 627/spi1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0% 3173/zygote64: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 424 minor 1 major
  0.1% 7/migration/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 23/migration/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 1344/kworker/u16:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 1383/kworker/u16:6: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 1827/s3c-fb-vsync: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 3199/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 243 minor 2 major
  0.1% 3490/kworker/1:6: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 4656/com.samsung.android.providers.context: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 315 minor 54 major
  0.1% 4797/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 688 minor 202 major
  0% 22517/com.sec.android.sidesync30: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 123 minor
  0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
  0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 6/kworker/u16:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 13/migration/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 18/migration/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 29/ksoftirqd/4: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 31/kworker/4:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 34/ksoftirqd/5: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 39/ksoftirqd/6: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 801/ion_noncontig_h: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1379/kworker/u16:5: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 2966/kworker/7:2H: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 307
```

Answer (score 2):

Iv'e encountered a similar ANR in my app. This often happens when the UI is blocked or when UI triggered-code takes too much time.

more specifically :

- No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
- A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr

If this issue is reproducible - I would separate all the code that runs at that point on the UI thread into two groups :

1. Code that HAS to run on the UI thread.
2. Code that can be moved to a background thread.

Then, of course, I'd move all the code from #2 to be executed in a background thread so that the control of the UI can be returned to the OS as soon as possible.